# how to connect my streamlit application with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, web-deployment, streamlit

So I am trying to use my (continously updating) database on MySQL with some visualizations which I want to put into my Streamlit app. In other words, I want to use the data from MySQL database in my Streamlit application.

> For this purpose I consulted the official streamlit documentation [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/mysql).

The problem here is that the tutorial tells me to create a file like this: `.streamlit/secrets.toml` and fill it with the following information (copy-pasting the syntax):

```
[
mysql
]
host = "localhost"
port = 3306
database = "xxx"
user = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
```

Everything was going good up until now but when I paste my `secret.toml` info in the SECRET MANAGEMENT widget (it is prompted when I am creating a new app in Streamlit cloud) it gives me a syntax error.

> Invalid format: please enter valid TOML.

Up untill this point I was going by the book(tutorial). Now to go over this I tried using only the variable definitions like following (since I am not aware of the `.toml` syntax):

```
db_user = "root"
db_name = "dbname"
db_password = "123abc"
```

Am I doing this right? Or am I missing something obvious?

---

With all of that aside, I also need to know how to call dependencies on stream cloud for my app. For example, I need `mysql-connector-python` module but I don't see any console with which I can do that

> NOTE:
> This is my first time deploying an app on the cloud

Answer (score 1):

```
[
mysql
]
```

It should be  `[mysql]`  in one line

In your GitHub repo, add `requirements.txt` file with your dependencies.

streamlit cloud will install those packages for your app.

Comment: Oh now I get it, up until now I was using PythonAnywhere and I had to manually install all dependencies on my own (also using the requirements.txt) but I didn't know the process was automatic in Streamlit. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want to notify another way we can use a database within a Streamlit App rather than using the conventional method.

We can refer to this [Medium.com article here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/importing-data-from-a-mysql-database-into-pandas-data-frame-a06e392d27d7).

It explains a way in which we can use `Pandas` Library to load a database and it also updates in real-time. By using this knowledge, connecting to a database becomes a "Python" problem, not a "streamlit" problem.

> Assuming we are using MySQL

We can, according to the [official tutorial](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases) for MySQL Database, create a `.streamlit/secrets.toml` file in which we will store our information(related to our database) as below:

```
# .streamlit/secrets.toml
[
mysql
]
host = "localhost"
port = 3306
database = "xxx"
user = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
```

Also install `mysql-connector-python` for python and import it on your application file. you will also need `Pandas` and `toml` Ofcourse:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python pandas toml
```

Here is what each of them do:
| Library | It's use |
| -------- | -------------- |
| mysql-connector-python | to connect to our database |
| pandas | to read and convert our database table into a Dataframe |
|toml| to read details from secrets.toml file |

#### STEP 1

We read details from `secrets.toml`

```
# Reading data
toml_data = toml.load("secrets.toml")
# saving each credential into a variable
HOST_NAME = toml_data['mysql']['host']
DATABASE = toml_data['mysql']['database']
PASSWORD = toml_data['mysql']['password']
USER = toml_data['mysql']['user']
PORT = toml_data['mysql']['port']
```

#### STEP 2

Connecting to our Database:

```
# Using the variables we read from secrets.toml
mydb = connection.connect(host=HOST_NAME, database=DATABASE, user=USER, passwd=PASSWORD, use_pure=True)
```

#### STEP 3

Making queries from our database:

```
query = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM mytable;' , mydb)
```

The `query` variable is now a display-able table in streamlit or Jupyter notebooks

Likewise, we can make any MySQL query(syntax applied) we want from our database.

> This information is based on my own experience.